# How I can stack elements above each other?

Tags: html, css, svg

So, i have this simple footer element within which i nested 4 svg images and a Paragraph.

```
    <img class="image1 svg" src="css/img/facebook.svg" alt="facebook_profile">
    <img class="image2 svg" src="css/img/tweeter.svg" alt="tweeter_profile">
    <img class="image3 svg" src="css/img/google-plus.svg" alt="google_plus_profile">
    <img class="image4 svg" src="css/img/skype.svg" alt="skype_account">

    <p class="copyright">&copy; 2017 Chirca Razvan</p>

</footer>
```

And these are the styles applied to it:

```
.svg {
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
    }

    .copyright {
        display: block;
        flex-basis: auto;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        background: rgb(9, 28, 41);
        padding: 30px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

[an visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JfXO.png)

I want to make that paragraph to appear below the images with some space between them.

Comment: Is using flexbox really necessary? In my opinion, you are using way too many css declarations, using only `text-align: center` suffices. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/vLajohfy/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to the paragraph, or change the `flex-basis` from `auto` to `100%`.

```css
.svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.copyright {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: auto;/*change to 100%*/
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #fff;
width: 100%;/*or add this*/
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgb(9, 28, 41);
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <img class="image1 svg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/F_icon.svg" alt="facebook_profile">
  <img class="image2 svg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg" alt="tweeter_profile">
  <img class="image3 svg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Logo_google%2B_2015.png" alt="google_plus_profile">
  <img class="image4 svg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Skype-icon.svg" alt="skype_account">
  <p class="copyright">&copy; 2017 Chirca Razvan</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <img class="image1 svg" src="css/img/facebook.svg" alt="facebook_profile">
  <img class="image2 svg" src="css/img/tweeter.svg" alt="tweeter_profile">
  <img class="image3 svg" src="css/img/google-plus.svg" alt="google_plus_profile">
  <img class="image4 svg" src="css/img/skype.svg" alt="skype_account">
</div>

<p class="copyright">&copy; 2017 Chirca Razvan</p>
```